# Does anyone know this forum script/software (see image)?

Tags: forum

I lately noticed many companies use the same forum software/script.

You find a progress bar on the right that "gets filled" as you scroll down (see image).

Does anyone know which forum software/script that is?

[image]

Thx

Gerd

Comment: You can check the source code to find indications what software is being used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the open source software [Discourse](https://www.discourse.org/) - that might be what you're searching for.

Comment: yes that is it. thank you